# I want to align the LearnMoreButton text next to h4 text. With the existing, the learn more shows in next line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, components

```
const Header: React.FC<Props> = ({ copy }: Props) => {
    if (isUndefined(copy)) return null;
    return (
        <Container>
            <img src={HeartCircle} />
            <Text>
                <h4>{copy.recommended.subheading}</h4>
                    <LearnMoreButton>
                        <RecommendedProviderLabel
                            isRecommendedProvider={true}
                            showIcon={false}
                            label={copy.ctas.learnMore}
                        />
                    </LearnMoreButton>
            </Text>
        </Container>
    );
```

Comment: What if `<Text style={{display: 'flex'}}>` instead of `<Text>`?

Comment: What css have you tried? Can you provide a screenshot? or better, a runnable sample that we can edit?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display flex`

```
flexRow: {
    display: flex;
  }

<div className={classes.flexRow}>
          <img src={HeartCircle} />
          <Text>
                <h4>{copy.recommended.subheading}</h4>
                    <LearnMoreButton>
                        <RecommendedProviderLabel
                            isRecommendedProvider={true}
                            showIcon={false}
                            label={copy.ctas.learnMore}
                        />
                    </LearnMoreButton>
            </Text>
        </div>
```